# how do you update data dictionary in python

Tags: python, data-dictionary

I am going through a json file and extracing "name" and "id" field. I need to form a data dictionary and store "name" and "id" fields in data dictionary called my_dict

```
report=("'name':{}, 'id':{}.format(content['name',content['id']
print(report)

'name': report1, 'id':1
```

I need to create and data dictionary and update the dictory with report values

I tried this:

```
my_dict.update(report)
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has lenght1, 2 is required
```

Comment: You need to add more clarity. `print(report)` looks strange/incorrect, you'll need to explain what it is. (Is it a `list` of `dict`?) What is `my_dict` beforehand? What do you expect `my_dict` to be afterwards?

Comment: `report` seems to be a string, not a dict; if this is confirmed, `my_dict.update(ast.literal_eval('{' + report + '}'))` should work.

Comment: @Swifty ast.literal_eval? NameError: name 'ast' is not defined

Comment: In your original post, you have multiple identical keys. Keys must be unique. Also, to create a dictionary: `report = {"name": content["name"], "id": content["id"]}`.

Comment: That said, your formatted string seems strange. And what is `content` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary and update the dictionary with the report values:

```
contents = [{'name': 'Ted', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'Fred', 'id': 2}]

# empty dict
my_dict = {}  

# loop through contents and add to dict
for content in contents:
    name = content['name']
    id_value = content['id']
    my_dict[name] = id_value

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Ted': 1, 'Fred': 2}
```